# Hearing first but understanding later?

Tags: terminology, memory, perception

I have experienced this phenomenon several times and checked with other people as well.

It goes like this: you hear something, but it's just a sound with no meaning. Some seconds later, you consciously remember the sound and make sense out of it (like a word or a phrase that somebody tells).

Although both processes (remembrance and understanding) are fairly common, I find it weird that understanding is not automatically triggered when processing a sound and it can be demanded on purpose

Is there any name for this phenomenon? (Would appreciate some detail on it too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phenomena broadly makes sense in terms of information processing models of memory and cognition.

#### The phonological loop

For example, you could think about the phenomena in terms of [a phonological loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baddeley%27s_model_of_working_memory#Phonological_loop). To Quote the Wikipedia article on [Baddeley's model of working memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baddeley%27s_model_of_working_memory#Phonological_loop)

> The phonological loop (or "articulatory loop") as a whole deals with
>   sound or phonological information. It consists of two parts: a
>   short-term phonological store with auditory memory traces that are
>   subject to rapid decay and an articulatory rehearsal component
>   (sometimes called the articulatory loop) that can revive the memory
>   traces.
>
> Any auditory verbal information is assumed to enter automatically into
>   the phonological store. Visually presented language can be transformed
>   into phonological code by silent articulation and thereby be encoded
>   into the phonological store. This transformation is facilitated by the
>   articulatory control process. The phonological store acts as an 'inner
>   ear', remembering speech sounds in their temporal order, whilst the
>   articulatory process acts as an 'inner voice' and repeats the series
>   of words (or other speech elements) on a loop to prevent them from
>   decaying. The phonological loop may play a key role in the acquisition
>   of vocabulary, particularly in the early childhood years.[3] It may
>   also be vital for learning a second language.

#### Applying this to the phenomena

- In the very short term (perhaps a few seconds), you presumably have a internal representation of the raw sound, which might if you were to attend to it afterwards be then processed into words and meaning.
- Alternatively, you may hear the words but not process the meaning. Presumably these words can remain represented for a little longer in your short term memory than can the raw sounds (as a very rough guess, perhaps up to 10 or 20 seconds). And then you can return to the words and process them.
- Another possibility is that you have basically processed the meaning of the original words, but were perhaps immediately distracted, and then a little later you remembered what was said and that you need to respond.